# Prove uniform convergence for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^n \sin\big( \frac{1}{3^nx} \big)$ with $x \in [a, \infty)$ where $a > 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove uniform convergence for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^n \sin\big( \frac{1}{3^nx} \big)$ with $x \in [a, \infty)$ where $a > 0$.

My approach was try to use that if $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly in an interval $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, then $f_n \rightarrow 0$ uniformly in $A$, but I can't make given $\epsilon > 0$ produce an expression only dependent on $\epsilon$. Is there a best approach to prove uniform convergenve in this serie?

Comment: Do you know Weierstrass M-test? It is the standard way to prove uniform convergence of series. (Indeed it will be very interesting to prove that the M-test is a valid test for uniform convergence, it will be not so hard.)

Comment: First, your logic in your sentence seems backwards. What's the standard tool *always* to start a uniform convergence series question? Weierstrass ...

Answer (score 3):

Using the fact that $\sin(t)\leq t$ for $t\geq 0$, it follows that
$$ 2^n\sin\Big(\frac{1}{3^nx}\Big)\leq \frac{2^n}{3^nx}\leq \frac{1}{a}\Big(\frac{2}{3}\Big)^n$$

Now you can apply the Weierstrass M-test to conclude that the series converges uniformly.